# Make grep output more readable

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, grep

I'm working with grep to patterns in files with `grep -orI "id=\"[^\"]\+\"" . | sort | uniq -d`
Which gives an output like the following:

```
./myFile.html:id="matchingR"
./myFile.html:id="other"
./myFile.html:id="cas"
./otherFile.html:id="what"
./otherFile.html:id="wheras"
./otherFile.html:id="other"
./otherFile.html:id="whatever"
```

What would be a convenient way to pipe this an have the following as output:

```
./myFile.html
  id="matchingR"
  id="other"
  id="cas"
./otherFile.html
  id="what"
  id="wheras"
  id="other"
  id="whatever"
```

Basically group results by filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the prettiest but it works.

```
awk -F : -v OFS=: 'f!=$1 {f=$1; print f} f==$1 {$1=""; $0=$0; sub(/^:/, "  "); print}'
```

If none of your lines can ever contain a colon then this simpler version also works.

```
awk -F : 'f!=$1 {f=$1; print f} f==$1 {$1=""; print}'
```

These both split fields on colons (`-F :`) print out the first field (filename) when it differs from a saved value (and save the new value) and when the first field matches the saved value they remove the first field and print. They differ in how they remove the field and print the output. The first attempts to preserve colons in the matched line. The second (and @fedorqui's version `... f==$1 {$0=$2; print}`) assume no other colons were on the line to begin with.

Comment: Good one. To me, `f==$1 {$0=$2; print}` would suffice. And if you want to print a tab, then `print "\t",$0` makes it. Also, OFS is not needed here.

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah, that would work for the second "no colons" version. That's what I get for working backward. The `OFS` is necessary in the first one to piece together any other colons on the line (e.g. a line of `./otherFile.html:id="wheras:foo"`).

Answer (score 0):

Pass output to this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 's/:/ /' | while read FILE TEXT; do
if [ "$FILE" = "$GROUP" ]; then
    echo "  $TEXT"
else
    GROUP="$FILE"
    echo "$FILE"
    echo "  $TEXT"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an short `awk`

```
awk -F: '{print ($1!=f?$1 RS:""),$2;f=$1}' file
./myFile.html
 id="matchingR"
 id="other"
 id="cas"
./otherFile.html
 id="what"
 id="wheras"
 id="other"
 id="whatever"
```